# Ballerina Native Build Fails with exit code 137 (OOM)

Tags: wso2, ballerina

The

```
bal build --native
```

command fails with the following error.

```
[1/7] Initializing...                                                                                   (16.3s @ 0.60GB)
 Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.2 Java 11 CE'
 Java version info: '11.0.19+7-jvmci-22.3-b18'
 C compiler: gcc (linux, x86_64, 7.5.0)
 Garbage collector: Serial GC
 2 user-specific feature(s)
 - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
 - io.ballerina.stdlib.crypto.svm.BouncyCastleFeature
[2/7] Performing analysis...  [************]                                                           (198.4s @ 3.66GB)
  27,643 (94.18%) of 29,352 classes reachable
 109,383 (84.89%) of 128,846 fields reachable
 166,411 (75.81%) of 219,506 methods reachable
   1,477 classes,   768 fields, and 2,931 methods registered for reflection
      91 classes,    93 fields, and    69 methods registered for JNI access
       7 native libraries: dl, m, pthread, rt, stdc++, z
[3/7] Building universe...                                                                              (20.4s @ 4.62GB)
[4/7] Parsing methods...      [*****]                                                                   (21.8s @ 4.05GB)
[5/7] Inlining methods...     [***]                                                                     (11.9s @ 5.56GB)
[6/7] Compiling methods...    [*****************]                                                      (295.5s @ 7.62GB)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 137
error: unable to create native image
```

This looks like an OOM issue. Are there any flags we can pass with bal build command to configure the memory limit? The VM I am executing this command has 14GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Ballerina does not support adding additional arguments to the `bal build --native` command. This is tracked via this issue: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/39200

But you can add additonal arguments by following these steps:

1. Create a file named `native-image.properties` and add the addtional options as `NativeImageArgs = <additional-arguments>`
2. So in your case you want to increase the memory, so add the following:

   ```
   NativeImageArgs = -J-Xmx14G
   ```
3. Before running the `bal build --native` command export the following to the terminal:

   ```
   export NATIVE_IMAGE_CONFIG_FILE=<absolute-path-of-native-image-properties>
   ```
4. Then run `bal build --native`

You can also add `--verbose` argument(this will print all the options) to the `NativeImageArgs` to make sure the arguments are picked up by the builder.

```
NativeImageArgs = -J-Xmx14G --verbose
```

If you still experience this issue after increasing the memory, then you can create an issue here: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues.

Ballerina has done some native build memory optimizations and this will be available in the next release - **Ballerina 2201.6.0**

Comment: Still no luck with this approach. I have created this issue as you suggested: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/40557